# Making a numpy array with a specific data format

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file which contains a log like this:

```
245     (click,view,view,check,view,view)         (22,1,5,6,7,15)

305     (view,run)       (5,6)

3051         (run,run)      (115,36)
```

It is tab seperated, the number of entries in the second column field is equal to the third column field.

I am finding it difficult to take this into python using np.loadtxt as it has a delimiter and text and brackets (circular) to separate the 2nd fields and 3rd fields.

Looking forward for suggestions on how I should go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it'd be best to parse it in some way with standard python first, before loading into numpy? Without knowing a lot about how numpy needs this to be formatted, below is an example to turn it into an array of arrays.

For instance you could use `split()`.

Def MakeItAList(lineFromFile):
    list = split(lineFromFile, " ")
    list[1] = split(list[1][1:-1],",")
    list[2] = split(list[2][1:-1],",")

It's a bit clunky but it will turn `245 (click,view,view,check,view,view) (22,1,5,6,7,15)`. into something like `[245, [click,view,view,check,view,view], [22,1,5,6,7,15]]` which is a little more manageable as a data-structure.